Unbiased estimators in uniform distributions
The variable $x$ is distributed uniformly in the interval $(a-1,a+1)$ where the value of $a$ is not known. A single observation of $x$ gave the value $x_1$.
How (with proof) do I use this value of $x_1$ to determine an unbiased estimate of $a$ and also determine the $99\%$ confidence limits for $a$?
I know that
$$E(x)=\frac{\int_{a-1}^{a+1} xf(x) \;\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{a-1}^{a+1} f(x) \;\mathrm{d}x}=a$$ but where to from there?

To wrap your head around this problem--especially if you're not familiar with theories and methods of unbiased estimation--why not start with simple guesses?  For instance, what is the expectation of $x$ and how does that relate to $a$?

You say what is the expectation of x. Am I correct in thinking that the way to do this is by moments of the form xf(x)dx? Candidate ideas would be that x1 is the best estimator of a or that E(x) gives a clue.

It looks like you're on the right track.

Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its
wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you
is grounds for closing.

You've already got an unbiased estimator of $a,$ with a proof that that's what it is (at least if you know how to evaluate the integrals that are in your question. To get a confidence interval, you'll have to exploit the fact that the length of the interval is known.

Because of the symmetry of the problem, a confidence interval should be $x\pm\text{something},$ i.e. the amounts after the $\text{“}{+}\text{”}$ and the $\text{“}{-}\text{”}$ should be the same. The question is: how much should that be in order to make the confidence level $99\%\text{?}$
$$
\Pr(x-s<a<x+s) = 0.99.
$$
The inequality $x-s<a$ is equivalent to $x<a+s$ and $a<x+s$ is equivalent to $a-s<x.$ So we want
$$
\Pr(a-s<x<a+s) = 0.99.
$$
$$
\Pr(a-0.99<x<a+0.99) = 0.99.
$$
So the probability that $a$ is between $x\pm0.99$ is $0.99.$
